# Is there a production ready webpack-server?

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I'm using `webpack-dev-server` to server my client side application (with angularjs).

The dev-server is working perfect but as far as I understand it should not be used at production.

Is there a production-ready equivalent server that I can use to serve my bundle.js? (I'm aware of the ability to implement my own server).

Comment: if your server relies on webpack transpilation, you can (should) export a server config which compiles your server and then run the output with a simple express server.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [simple server in Node](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) or use a framework such as [express](http://expressjs.com/).

The reason [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) isn't recommended for production use is because it's designed to update the browser when files change which isn't desirable in production.